Unusual language in NP
Under the assumptions $\text{NP} \neq \text{coNP}$ and $\text{P}\neq\text{NP}\cap \text{coNP}$, we need to prove that
there is a language $L$ that satisfies the following:

$L\notin \text{P}$.
$L\in \text{NP}$.
$L$ is not $\text{NP-complete}$.

At first, I thought maybe an example of such language would suffice, but it demands to see $L$ as a general language and since that, I've been stuck.

just so I'll know for the next time, what was the problem with my original post?

I mainly used latex when writing \in, \notin. Etc. Also made the names  NP, coNP look nicer.

Under the assumptions in the question, you can simply take a language $L\in (\text{NP}\cap \text{coNP}) \setminus \text{P}$ (note that such a language exists by the assumptions as $\text{P}\subseteq \text{NP}\cap \text{coNP}$ always holds). Clearly, $L$ satisfies 1. and 2. It thus left to show that $L$ satisfies 3., but this is also immediate as if by contradiction $L$ is $\text{NP-complete}$, then:

For all $K\in \text{coNP}$, we get that $\overline{K}\leq_p L$, and as $L\in \text{coNP}$, we conclude that $\overline{K} \in \text{coNP}$. So we have in total that $K\in \text{NP}$ for all $K\in \text{coNP}$. Hence, $\text{coNP}\subseteq \text{NP}$.

For all $K\in \text{NP}$, we get that $K\leq_p L$, and as $L\in \text{coNP}$, we conclude that $K \in \text{coNP}$. So we have in total that $K\in \text{coNP}$ for all $K\in \text{NP}$. Hence, $\text{NP}\subseteq \text{coNP}$.


and we have reached a contradiction to the assumption that $\text{NP} \neq \text{coNP}$. So it all comes does to the fact that if you have a language in $\text{coNP}$ that is also $\text{NP-complete}$, then $\text{NP}$ and $\text{coNP}$ collapse to the same class.
